# R- unique and common items across each of three vectors (or data frame columns) for venn diagram

Tags: r, join, dplyr, unique, intersection

I am trying to compare three different vectors of different length for unique and overlapping elements using R.  Each of the elements contains a string ("label" of interest) for further analysis via a venn diagram. No duplicate elements exist in any of the string.

Can somebody please suggest a simple way to select all unique and common elements for each vector - "ad", "ld", and "md" in the example below?

```
ad<-c("abc 1", "cd4", "efg9", "hij 2", "kl 2N", "mno1", "pq22", "rs5", 
"wv92", "da2")
ld<-c("cd4", "hij 2", "xy3", "xyz 2", "vw9", "pq22", "lm3", "p3", "da2")
md<-c("pq22", "da2", "ef44", "hi9", "q1", "r 44")
```

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: how about `VennDiagram::get.venn.partitions(list(ad=ad, ld=ld, md=md))`

Comment: To clarify:  I would like to extract what is unique in "ad", unique in "ld", unique in "md". common to "ad" and "ld", common to "ld and md", common to "ad" and "md", common to "ad", "ld", "md", and finally (ideally) convert input these to a venn diagram.

Comment: @sribandhakavi ; just use the `VennDiagram` package ie  to see the sets `VennDiagram::get.venn.partitions(list(ad=ad, ld=ld, md=md))`, and to plot the venn `grid::grid.draw(VennDiagram::venn.diagram(list(ad=ad, ld=ld, md=md), NULL))`

Comment: @user20650 - this almost works! However it is overlaying this venn diagram over the last image generated on my Rstudio IDE. Any idea why?

Comment: yes, you need to call `grid.newpage()` before each new plot to clear the previous (as in all grid graphics)

Comment: Try `Reduce(intersect,list(ad,ld,md))`. Try using `union()` for all unique elements.

Comment: @user20650 - this worked well for the above example vectors but I am having some issues with my actual vectors...may repost if I cant fix this but you answer is correct. Thank you@Brian - this is also elegant, but I will go with solution of user20650 because of the connection to venn diagram output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @user20650 for the answer to above question. The following code is the solution:

```
VennDiagram::get.venn.partitions(list(ad=ad, ld=ld, md=md))
grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(VennDiagram::venn.diagram(list(ad=ad, ld=ld, md=md), NULL))
```